# How is it possible to get the forms mouse position when clicking inside a control?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, mouse-position

- I have a panel and have added a PictureBox to it.
- I have added mouse_click listeners to both the panel and the picturebox.
- When they are clicked i create a messagebox which tells me the mouse position.

Problem:

- When i click the panel, i get the mouse position i want.
- When i click the pictureBox, i get the current position in that picturebox.

What i want:

- I want both of the controls to get the current mouseposition on the form.
- I can also go with getting the current mouseposition of the panel, since it is overlaying the form.

Does anybody know how i can do this?
I've googled around for this, but can't seem to find anything about it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

see PointToScreen and PointToClient methods on the control.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the position from the entire form just add the width and height of those items to your point.